# Azure Functions Out of Memory Exceptions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, out-of-memory, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Functions Powershell core as below:

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param([byte[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write out the blob name and size to the information log.
Write-Host "PowerShell Blob trigger function Processed blob! Name: $($TriggerMetadata.Name) Size: $($InputBlob.Length) bytes  Uri: $($TriggerMetadata.Uri)"
```

By using a Blob Trigger i want to read VDH OS images with Powershell from Azure Blob  and convert them to managed disk. The size of the image is 30GB. When the function is triggered, i get the **System.OutOfMemoryException** below:

```
2020-09-07T09:52:44.704 [Error] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=93b00718-9941-4379-abd0-348137cdcff2, Duration=56449ms)Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
2020-09-07T09:52:45.061 [Information] Stopping JobHost
```

I have increased the App Plan in order to have 14GB of memory but i got the same memory exception.

When i do this operation directly from **Cloud Shell**, i get **success** but my main aim is to **automize** the script with **Blob Trigger**.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 9):

Check the platform configuration of the Function App :

**Function -> Configuration -> General Settings -> Platform**

[image]

The 32 Bit will have less private bytes and it can hit the out of memory exceptions even though the instance has much more capacity.

If this is your case, recommend you to upgrade to the **64 bit**.

Comment: with the consumption plan, i still get the out of memory exceptions. With 14GB app plan, i have now [Error] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=5a9b8ae0-3fbb-40fa-9797-488319c15384, Duration=88405ms)Stream was too long.

Comment: Why is this answer not popular, This has solved a big issue of ours ! Thanks a lot !
We are inserting 1 million objects with 50 properties each - ran successfully in local console app, but always failed in azure function. upgraded to 64 bit and everything works smoothly